# VScode connected with WSL "The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working."

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pty

I have `wsl 2` installed on windows 10 and I have connected `VScode` with `wsl`. Many times when I run a `gatsby` app in `VScode` with the `wsl` environment. I get the error:

```
The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working.
```

I have disabled and uninstalled many `VScode` extensions, did a `BIOS` update and have the latest version of `VScode` but the problem stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the option: `terminal.integrated.terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty`

[image]

Source: [Connection to terminal's pty host process is becoming unresponsive](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130320#issuecomment-916569599)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's an old problem that has returned: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7964

I solved it by uninstalling version 1.79 and installing 1.78.2.
It worked for me, but keep downgrading if it doesn't for you. I believe the original issue was solved in version 1.76

Answer (score -2):

1. Run `flutter clean` in terminal
2. `Restart` VSCode
3. Run `flutter get package`

Repeat

Comment: What about win 10? I am not even able to start a terminal in vscode on win 10.

Comment: This has nothing to do with flutter